# first member of each item in a dictionary needs to be an array

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, ms-word

I have a code that loops through a document, then stores each single word in a dictionary. Each key in the dictionary is the “word” itself and each dict. item corresponding to that key is an array which has the (start and end) ranges of that word. if the shows multiple times, we simply add the new ranges to the dict. item array, meaning that the item array has become an array of arrays where each sub array holds the ranges of word instance “n”. as illustrated in this picture.

[image: dictionary structure]

**The problem is**: each first sub array in each dictionary item is separated into two arrays, one storing the start range and one storing the end range as seen in the watches window. I need just one array storing both of these values, the later sub arrays are fine.

[image: watches window]

When I get to the code of highlighting, I want to highlight the words that show “x” number of times according to some user input. While the above issue is standing, each word appears to show “x+1” times, for instance if a word found “3” times, the number of items for that word say it shows “4” times which is wrong, I can fix it by subtracting (1) but I don’t want that. and yes I can write a code that highlight words with “x” frequency using “find” method.

[image]

**here is the full code**

```
Sub MapWordsAndHighlight()
    Dim WordsDict As Object

    'a dict. to hold words and their range values
    Set WordsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'an object representing each word in the cgosen document
    Dim WordObject As Variant

    'a temp. arr. to hold range values while adding new ones
    Dim TmpRangeArrOfDupWords() As Variant

    'the new upper bound of the tmp arr to recive the new values
    Dim TmpArrayNewUpperBound As Long

    'string that represents each words in the chosen document
    Dim SingleWord As String

    Dim i As Long
    'loop through each word in current document
    For Each WordObject In ActiveDocument.Range.Words

        'remove the surrounding spaces and store the word string
        SingleWord = Trim(WordObject.Text)

        'skip single characters
        If Len(SingleWord) > 1 Then

            'check if the word is not stored previously in the dict
            If Not WordsDict.Exists(SingleWord) Then
                WordsDict.Add Key:=SingleWord, Item:=GetWordRangeArray(WordObject)
            Else

                'dump old range vlaues into tmp array
                TmpRangeArrOfDupWords = WordsDict(SingleWord)

                'make a new place in tmp arr for new ranges
                TmpArrayNewUpperBound = UBound(TmpRangeArrOfDupWords) + 1

                'expand the tmp array
                ReDim Preserve TmpRangeArrOfDupWords(1 To TmpArrayNewUpperBound)

                'store new ranges at the last placein tmp arr
                TmpRangeArrOfDupWords(TmpArrayNewUpperBound) = GetWordRangeArray(WordObject)
                WordsDict(SingleWord) = TmpRangeArrOfDupWords
                Erase TmpRangeArrOfDupWords
            End If
        End If
    Next
    '============================================================
    '** this part highlights words that are repeated "n" times
    'loop through dict. items array
    For Each var In WordsDict.Keys
        'replace the "2" with "n" if you want to highlight the words that are repeated "n" times
        If UBound(WordsDict.Item(var)) = 2 Then
            ThisDocument.Range(WordsDict.Item(var)(1), WordsDict.Item(var)(2)).HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        End If
    Next
    '============================================================
End Sub

Function GetWordRangeArray(WordObject) As Variant()
'static variant array of two item
    Dim RangeValue(1 To 2)

    'store the starting range
    RangeValue(1) = WordObject.Start

    'store the end range, (-1) neglect space at the end of word
    RangeValue(2) = WordObject.End - 1

    'returned value
    GetWordRangeArray = RangeValue

    'clear the array
    Erase RangeValue
End Function
```

Comment: Given that a word has an easy to determine length, why not just store the start of each occurrence?

Comment: @John Coleman..thanks your idea works.but i need to solve this issue. here is the new code changes that worked according to your idea inline `code` Dim RangeValue(1 To 1) RangeValue(1) = WordObject.Start and `code` ThisDocument.Range(WordsDict.Item(var)(1), WordsDict.Item(var)(1) + Len(var))

Comment: Arrays based 1 is a must?

Comment: @omegastripes... no it's not a must.. i tried zero based , same result

Comment: Also there is an issue with `WordObject.End - 1`: dot or comma etc. following the word cuts off the last letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your dictionary values to each be an array of 2-member arrays then you need to start out with

```
Array(Array(a,b))
```

which you can then extend to

```
Array(Array(a,b), Array(c,d))
```

and not

```
Array(a,b) >> Array(a,b, Array(c,d))
```

which is what your current code does.

Fixed:

```
Sub MapWordsAndHighlight()

    Dim WordObject As Variant
    Dim TmpRangeArrOfDupWords() As Variant
    Dim TmpArrayNewUpperBound As Long
    Dim SingleWord As String
    Dim i As Long, var, arr
    Dim WordsDict As Object

    Set WordsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each WordObject In ActiveDocument.Range.Words

        SingleWord = Trim(WordObject.Text)


        If Len(SingleWord) > 1 Then
            If Not WordsDict.Exists(SingleWord) Then
                WordsDict.Add Key:=SingleWord, Item:=GetWordRangeArray(WordObject)
            Else
                WordsDict(SingleWord) = GetWordRangeArray(WordObject, _
                                               WordsDict(SingleWord))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each var In WordsDict.Keys
        If UBound(WordsDict.Item(var)) = 2 Then
            arr = WordsDict.Item(var)
            ThisDocument.Range(arr(1)(1), arr(1)(2)).HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        End If
    Next
    '============================================================
End Sub

Function GetWordRangeArray(WordObject, Optional arr) As Variant()

    Dim RangeValue(1 To 2), ub

    RangeValue(1) = WordObject.Start
    RangeValue(2) = WordObject.End - 1

    If IsMissing(arr) Then
        Dim rv(1 To 1)
        rv(1) = RangeValue
        GetWordRangeArray = rv
    Else
        ub = UBound(arr) + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To ub)
        arr(ub) = RangeValue
        GetWordRangeArray = arr
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thanks Tim, this is actually your code slightly modified because i wanted to store strings inside the dictionary and not objects, i'll try the new code

Comment: I did recognize it...  ;-)

Comment: I'm learning new stuff just by reading your code, thanks and i hope you help in the next questions because there will be next stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

I've slightly reworked your code, now it works OK.

What were modified:

1. Method for check if any range array for certain word exists in the dictionary. If there is not, then start from empty array. That approach fixes the issue of the first member of each item in the dictionary.
2. `Function GetWordRangeArray()` is abolished, native `Array()` function is used for range array creation, so it becomes zero-based.
3. Method of computing the word end `WordObject.Start + Len(SingleWord))`, since there is no the trailing space at the nend of the word when it followed by dot or comma, so the original code cuts off the last letter instead of the trailing space.
4. Nested loop was added to highlight each occurance of each word of certain length.

```vb
Sub MapWordsAndHighlight()

    'a dict. to hold words and their range values
    Dim WordsDict As Object

    'an object representing each word in the cgosen document
    Dim WordObject As Variant

    'a temp. arr. to hold range values while adding new ones
    Dim TmpRangeArrOfDupWords As Variant

    'the new upper bound of the tmp arr to recive the new values
    Dim TmpArrayNewUpperBound As Long

    'string that represents each words in the chosen document
    Dim SingleWord As String

    Dim i As Long

    Dim CurrentWord As Variant

    Dim CurrentArr As Variant

    Set WordsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'loop through each word in current document
    For Each WordObject In ActiveDocument.Range.Words

        'remove the surrounding spaces and store the word string
        SingleWord = Trim(WordObject.Text)

        'skip single characters
        If Len(SingleWord) > 1 Then

            'dump old range values into tmp array, empty element will be created if not exists
            TmpRangeArrOfDupWords = WordsDict(SingleWord)

            'check if the old range didn't exist
            If Not IsArray(TmpRangeArrOfDupWords) Then TmpRangeArrOfDupWords = Array()

            'make a new place in tmp arr for new ranges
            TmpArrayNewUpperBound = UBound(TmpRangeArrOfDupWords) + 1

            'expand the tmp array
            ReDim Preserve TmpRangeArrOfDupWords(TmpArrayNewUpperBound)

            'store new ranges at the last place in tmp arr
            TmpRangeArrOfDupWords(TmpArrayNewUpperBound) = Array(WordObject.Start, WordObject.Start + Len(SingleWord))
            WordsDict(SingleWord) = TmpRangeArrOfDupWords
            Erase TmpRangeArrOfDupWords
        End If
    Next

    '============================================================
    '** this part highlights words that are repeated "n" times
    'loop through dict. items array
    For Each CurrentWord In WordsDict.Keys
        'replace the "2" with "n" if you want to highlight the words that are repeated "n" times
        If UBound(WordsDict(CurrentWord)) + 1 = 2 Then
            For Each CurrentArr In WordsDict(CurrentWord)
                ThisDocument.Range(CurrentArr(0), CurrentArr(1)).HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
            Next
        End If
    Next
    '============================================================
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, as for the `WordObject.End - 1` i meant to do that to cut off the trailing space at the end of the word since ms-word considers the word as string with a space at the end

Comment: @Ali_R4v3n, there is no the trailing space at the end of the word when it followed by dot or comma, so your initial code cuts off the last letter instead of the trailing space, that is an issue. That is why I use another way to get the word end.

Comment: @Ali_R4v3n, I added the description what changes were made.

Comment: thanks very much, i have faced the dot issue in another project and handled it by testing the last letter of each word if its a character or not. but i didn't do that in this code, thanks again for mentioning it